# Toroidal gravitational field from Gauss theorem?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, gauss-law

Even if complicated, can the gravitational field of a uniform toroid of radii $R$ and $r$ be calculated with the Gauss theorem? I know that we can guess the gravitational field of a RING but I have never seen if the field of an axisymmetric doughnut can be estimated with the aid of the Gauss flux theorem. Can it be done?

Comment: Is this helpful? [Gravitational force due to a ring](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/756843/226902)

Comment: Related: https://www.aleph.se/andart/archives/2014/02/torusearth.html It's a slightly modified rotating torus.